# IF statements combining multiple columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, multiple-columns

I am using excel 2010 and looking to use IF statements to add multiple columns that have both letters and numbers. I have come as far as to get all the coding in so that when one of each condition is presented they total correctly.

The problem I am having is if there is more than one of the same condition.

For example the IF statement I am using is: `=IF(ISNA(MATCH("1P",C7:CO7,0)),0,1)+IF(ISNA(MATCH("2P",C7:CO7,0)),0,2)` and so on.

Obviously between cells C7 and CO7 there are many cells and if more than one cell has 1P or 2P in it the additional cells are not being added and only one. How can I get my formula to recognize the condition in more than one cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`=COUNTIF(C7:CO7,"1P")+2*COUNTIF(C7:CO7,"2P")` should get you the answer you need

Edit: Fixed formula - thanks @Andy

Comment: I think you meant `=COUNTIF(C7:CO7,"1P")+2*COUNTIF(C7:CO7,"2P")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a flexible approach that allows for an arbitrary number of match values and multipliers, you could try this.

Make a little table somewhere of Match Values and corresponding Multipliers and use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($C$7:$CO$7=$A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5,0))
```

Commit the array formula by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

[image]

*Note my screen shot truncates the data range. 14 is the correct answer for the data I entered.*